# How to debug a hung hadoop map-reduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I run MR Job, Map Phase run successful, but Reduce Phase complied at 33% and hang (hanging about 1 hour) status: "reduce > sort"
How i can debug it?

Comment: how many reducers do you have set, what's the value of the map and shuffle / reducer parameters?(http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html). How many records were output from your map stage?

Answer (score 1):

It may be nothing to do with your case, but I had this happen when IPTABLES (~firewall) was mis-configured on one node. When that node was assigned a reducer role, the reduce phase would hang at 33%. Check the error logs to make sure the connections are working, especially if you have recently added new nodes and/or configured them manually.